# How to check a specific class type exists in the inheritance chain

Tags: java, reflection, decorator

I have a class which is implements the decorator pattern. I need to check whether a specific class appear in the inheritance chain. Normally, I would just use `instanceof`.

However, I don't have the class definition during dev time. In other words, I get the class name (as a `String`) at run time. In this situation, how could I check this given class name appears in the inheritance chain?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, sounds horrible. Reflection is usually a really bad idea.

**Edit:** As @Holger points out in the comments, dynamic checking of type hierarchies is also a really bad idea. (Shame there's more than one new language feature coming for that. Ho hum.) Even more generally, keep your type hierarchies flat. But that's a whole new kettle of fish. In my experience, it's reflection that typically (not always, Credit Suisse!) highlights and promotes confusion.

Having said that: You will, of course, need the fully qualified class name (although you could probe a sequence of packages). From there, `Class.forName` methods will allow you to recover the `Class` object (though if you are using multiple class loaders, it could get messier). Then you just need `Class.isAssignableFrom`.

Comment: I wouldn’t focus on Reflection as the bad idea, but the actual requirement, i.e. that without actually knowing X or Y, insisting on X being a subtype of Y instead of just letting X fulfill the relevant contract in whatever way it wants.